# How to check if the value exists in the element of an array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the array given below, I intend to check if any males are present in the records

```
const data = {
city: "london",
records: [
  { name: "sam", gender: "male" },
  { name: "wendy", gender: "female" }
]
};
```

I am new to typescript and unable to understand the usage of some() function when traversing an array of the dictionary as mentioned above, how can that be done?

Comment: `Array.prototype.some`

Comment: Can you be clear, for this case data.records. ??

Comment: Even assuming the lack of a `some` method--simply iterate and check the `gender` property. It's unclear what the problem is; did something not work with what you tried?

Comment: @DivikShrivastava you gotta put some effort in. `Array.prototype.some` is documented in numerous places across the internet. You have to try something.

Comment: @TKoL I was clear of the use of .some() function but just not how to use it for a dictionary array element, as mentioned in one of the answers, still I will try hard next time before posting here.

Comment: An array is an array--where it "lives" isn't relevant :)

Comment: @DaveNewton I know an array is an array yet for a beginner it's not really straight forward to traverse the one mentioned like above, eventually I had to use map(), filter() and some() functions to finally get comfortable with it's usage in future, but I am glad how supportive people are at stack overflow, specially when you are blocked and your question is closed really kicks up the motivation when trying something new, specially the line "an array is an array" is the smartest one yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.some` method on array, example:

```js
var arr = [
  { name: "sam", gender: "male" },
  { name: "wendy", gender: "female" }
];

arr.some(item => item.gender === 'male'); // true
```

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the presence with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const data = {
  city: "london",
  records: [
    { name: "sam"   , gender: "male"   },
    { name: "wendy" , gender: "female" }
  ]
};

const hasMales = data.records.some(({ gender }) => gender === 'male');

console.log(hasMales); // true
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const data = {
  city: "london",
  records: [
    { name: "sam"   , gender: "male"   },
    { name: "wendy" , gender: "female" }
  ]
};

const hasMales = data.records.find(({ gender }) => gender === 'male') !== null;

console.log(hasMales); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the records arrry, like so:

```js
const data = {
city: "london",
records: [
  { name: "sam", gender: "male" },
  { name: "wendy", gender: "female" }
]
};


let hasMales = false;
data.records.forEach(person => {
  if (person.gender === "male") {
    hasMales = true;
    return; // stop enumerating on first male
  }
});

console.log(hasMales);
```